# Efficiently retrieve less objects from Database with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this C# code:

```
List<int> myList = getList();          
using (var context = new SOSUtenzeEntities())            
{
    return context.Users.Where(X => myList.Contains(X.UserId)).ToList();
}
```

I want to retrieve only Users whose UserId is contained in `myList` because I do not need all of them, but the code I provided is as fast as

```
List<int> myList = getList();          
using (var context = new SOSUtenzeEntities())            
{
    List<Users> userList = context.Users.ToList();
    userList = userList.Where(X => myList.Contains(X.UserId);
    return userList;
}
```

which is not very much efficient 'cause I am retrieving all the Users from the database and only then filter it. Is there a better way around it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first way looks fine to me, unless `myList` is massive, in which case you'll hit problems. Have you seen performance issues, or is this a case of premature optimisation?

Comment: if your `context.Users` is currently very small, the two queries may be swamped by network time and be very similar, but only the first query will scale as the number of `Users` gets very large.